# How do I create a instance for Constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

I cannot create object for this coding.  How can I access this values I want to return the `msg` value in this coding?

```
package com.my;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.VectorAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;
import java.util.Vector;
public class LogCapture 
    {
    private final VectorAppender appender;
    private final Level level;
    public LogCapture(final Level level)
        {
        this.level = level;
        Logger root = Logger.getRootLogger();
        appender = new VectorAppender();
        root.addAppender(appender);
        }
public static void main(String args[])
{
    new LogCapture(Level.INFO);

    LogCapture.getMessage() ;
}
    public String getMessage()
        {
        Vector vector = appender.getVector();
        String msg = null;
        switch (vector.size())
            {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            LoggingEvent event = (LoggingEvent) vector.elementAt(0);
            msg = event.getRenderedMessage();
            break;
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

Comment: With respect, you've been on the site over a month and asked eight previous questions, but you're still not formatting code correctly. It's well worth reading the **How to Format** box to the right of the question area, as well as [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) talking about formatting in more detail. The more effort you put into your question, the better both the quality and quantity of answers you'll receive. **Edit**: Crozin's done it for you this time, but for next time, it's really worth doing it yourself.

Comment: I don't understand the question. @Op. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to get the value of msg..how can i do?

Comment: switching on vector.size() is strange. I'd expect a for loop or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the question, but it sounds easy. You create an instance like this:

```
new LogCapture(Level.INFO);
```

You can find the other log levels here:
[Documentation for Level](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html)

Edit (since the OP has added some more code):
Change the code in the main method so that it says

```
LogCapture logCapture = new LogCapture(Level.INFO);
logCapture.getMessage();
```

Comment: i want to get the value of msg..how can i do?

Comment: What? Looks like your method `getMessage()` returns the msg.

Comment: But i dunno how to cal this method?

Comment: You invoke it in the same way as you invoke any method. First create an instance in the same way as I posted in my answer, assign it to an attribute or variabel, and then invoke `getMessage`. E.g `logCapture.getMessage()`

Comment: i cant cal the getmessage method

Comment: That isn't a very good explanation of the problem, and I'm not a mind reader. Do you get an exception? What does it say? Do you get a compilation error? What does it say?

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getMessage() from the type LogCapture Error is like that..i got compiler error,My modified coding is here[Coding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235925/how-do-i-create-a-instance-for-constructor)